# The usb drive with Debian with UEFI can't be powered on on another old PC with UEFI on

Tags: debian, usb-drive

I installed the Debian system on a usb drive with UEFI and I can boot it in two computers by inserting it. However, in my old PC (Aspire E 15 E5-571G-57D9), the usb drive can't be boot with UEFI enabled on the old PC. In the BIOS setting, I can't see the usb of the Debian system, but I can boot a usb drive with Windows PE in that old PC. The system BIOS version is V1.22 in BIOS setting.

Why can't I boot this Debian on the old PC?

Thanks.

Comment: `The system BIOS version is V1.22` a BIOS version by itself is meaningless, I have 4 different computers with BIOS versions 4.1, 4.9, 7.3 and 7.4 - all of which are the latest for that particular hardware

Comment: there's all sorts of UEFI settings that can affect boot. CSM, USB mode, Secure Boot, etc etc etc

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add at least brand/model.

Comment: @JaromandaX Even disabled the secure boot, it still can't boot on Debian by USB. What is the CSM?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, I have added the brand and the exact model of the old PC.

Comment: Upgrade to latest BIOS version : [1.32](https://www.acer.com/ca-en/support?search=Aspire%20E5-571G&filter=global_download&suggest=E5-571G;1)

Answer (score 4):

A removable media is bootable in UEFI mode when it contains a FAT partition (ideally FAT32, but newer UEFI versions accept other forms of FAT too), which contains the appropriate boot file in the `\EFI\BOOT\` directory: for the x86_64 architecture, the boot file name is `BOOTX64.EFI`.

(If Secure Boot is enabled, it adds a requirement that either the boot file must be signed with a certificate that's on Secure Boot approved list, or the hash of the file (usually SHA-256) must be specifically whitelisted.)

According to the UEFI specification, the boot filename should be case insensitive, but some early UEFI implementations were case sensitive instead.

Check the character case of the full path of the UEFI boot file on the Windows PE USB, and then make sure the Debian USB uses the exact same character case for its boot file (change if necessary).

Since the operating system's FAT32 driver may consider upper and lower case versions of the filename effectively the same, you might have to first temporarily rename the file or directory to something else and then back in order to get the character case corrected. For example, in Linux:

```
mv bootx64.efi BOOTX64.EFI     # this won't change the character case
mv: 'bootx64.efi' and 'BOOTX64.EFI' are the same file

mv bootx64.efi foo.efi
mv foo.efi BOOTX64.EFI         # character case successfully changed
```

If the old system has been receiving Windows updates recently, it may have received a fairly recent UEFI blacklist update (Windows update KB5012170) that invalidated Debian's old Secure Boot key (among others), as the bootloaders signed with that old key were vulnerable to BootHole and/or related security exploits. Although the UEFI blacklist update has been distributed through Windows updates, it is more like a firmware update - it updates the UEFI Secure Boot signed blacklist variable (`dbx`), which is used by the firmware and OS-independent.

If your Debian installation media is older than, say, late 2021, it might be still using the vulnerable bootloader version which is now blacklisted, and so Secure Boot might be stopping it from booting. Most distributions that had bootloaders with the BootHole vulnerability have by now provided updated versions of their installation images with fixed bootloaders and/or new keys as appropriate.

---

If you find the bootloader files only in `\EFI\debian\`, and not in `\EFI\boot\`, then the USB may only be bootable on the system that it was installed in, because on UEFI systems, `grub-install` will also create a UEFI NVRAM boot variable (effectively a BIOS setting) that identifies the bootloader location. This will not travel along with the USB removable media. As a result, the USB is expected to boot only on the system that created it (and possibly on systems that created an exactly similar USB media in the past and haven't deleted the NVRAM boot variable for it).

Some systems may have a more forgiving UEFI implementation and automatically seek for any bootable `*.EFI` file from any filesystem type the UEFI firmware can read, but this is not guaranteed by the UEFI specification.

However, as you have a computer that will successfully boot the USB, this will be easy to fix: just boot from the USB, then run `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --force-extra-removable /dev/sdX` (replace `sdX` with the actual whole-disk device for the USB). This will make `grub-install` write a second copy of the essential boot files into `\EFI\BOOT\` directory of the ESP. Now the ESP will have a second copy of the bootloader written into a location where even the most strict UEFI implementation should look for it when booting from a removable media.

Comment: Thanks for your kindle reply. I check that the boot file is in the `\ESP\EFI\debian`, which is weird as it is `debian` not `BOOT`, but this structrue can be booted in most of PC except the that old PC. In `debian` folder, there are six files: `BOOTX64.CSV`, `fbx64.efi`, `grub.cfg`, `grubx64.efi`, `mmx64.efi`, `shimx64.efi`, which is not the case as you said.  Why?

Comment: May you tell me why `mv bootx64.efi BOOTX64.EFI     # this won't change the character case`?

Comment: See my edit for your first comment. For the second, this is because Linux's FAT32 driver is implemented properly: it is case-insensitive but case-preserving, so it considers a `mv` that only changes the character case as identical to `mv foo foo`: a meaningless operation, because the character case should not matter on a FAT filesystem. A side effect of this is, if you actually *want* to change just the character case of a filename on a FAT filesystem, you will have to temporarily rename it to something else, and then back to the original name with the desired character case.

Comment: There are several questions: 1. I can see there is `\EFI\debian\ ` in `genius disk` in Windows 11, how can I see this structure in Debian 11? As with `lsblk`, it shows `\sda\sda1` with `part /boot/efi`, witch is not the same as `\EFI\debian\ ` . 2. When I run the code `grub-install --force-extra-removable /dev/sda`, there is `bash: grub-install: command not found`, even if I had successfully run the code `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get install grub`. How should solve it? Thanks.

Comment: In Windows, each filesystem/partition is usually treated as separate, identified by *drive letters*. In Linux, all filesystems are *mounted* into a single directory tree. The currently-used ESP is mounted to `/boot/efi/` in Debian, so Windows's `[some letter]:\EFI\DEBIAN\ ` will be `/boot/efi/EFI/DEBIAN/` in Linux.

Comment: Bootloader installation is a privileged operation, so it needs to be done as root, or with `sudo`. So `sudo grub-install --force-extra-removable /dev/sda` when booted on the USB.

Comment: 1. As I want to learn the file structure as you knew, which book I should read? 2. Can I change the name of folder, `debain`, to `BOOT` directly? 3. As I run `sudo grub-install --force-extra-removable /dev/sda`, the terminal outputs: `sudo grub-install --force-extra-removable /dev/sda
Unrecognized option '--force-extra-removable'
Usage: grub-install [OPTION] install_device
Install GRUB on your drive.`

Comment: 2. Changing only the folder name will not be sufficient - you would also need to rename an `*.efi` file within that folder (either `grubx64.efi` or `shimx64.efi`) to `bootx64.efi`, and the `grubx64.efi` may include a built-in reference to `\EFI\DEBIAN\grub.cfg` which you won't be able to change without invalidating the Secure Boot signature. It is better to use the proper tool. 3.) The error suggests you may be trying to install a BIOS version of GRUB, which does not have that option. Add the `--target=x86_64-efi` option (see edit above).

Comment: After done so, I have successfully seen the `BOOT` folder. Can I delete the `debian` folder now?

Comment: No, don't delete it. As I said above, the `grubx64.efi` (even in the `BOOT` folder) may still use the `grub.cfg` file in the `debian` folder. But now try the USB in your Aspire E 15; it should be UEFI bootable now.